# mysql ERROR 1426 (42000): Too big precision 14 specified for column 'time'. Maxi mum is 6

Tags: mysql

guy. I have a strange trouble When I try create a table with timestamp type.

```
create table `test`
 ( `time` timestamp(14) );
```

*ERROR 1426 (42000): Too big precision 14 specified for column 'time'. Maximum is 6.*

I thought the `14` is a bytes lengths for storage. But it seems like the time precision, because 6 = microsecond(1/1000000), 2012-07-29 00:37:46.***000000***

Anybody can explain it ? I didn't find it in online documentation!
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Timestamp columns use the [unix timestamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) format and you can't control their precision, they are always 4 bytes (5 if null-able). Try

```
create table `test` ( `time` timestamp );
```