# SQLSyntaxErrorException while trying to create a MySQL table with Java ResultSet metadata

Tags: java, mysql

```
for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++ )
{
    if ( i > 1 ) sb.append( ", " );
    String colname=rsmetadata.getColumnName(i);
    String datatype=rsmetadata.getColumnTypeName(i);
    int sizedata=rsmetadata.getColumnDisplaySize(i);
    //System.out.println("column is  "+colname+"#"+datatype+"#"+sizedata);
    sb.append(colname).append(" ").append(datatype);
    int precision = rsmetadata.getPrecision(i);
    if ( precision != 0 )
    {
        sb.append( "( " ).append( precision ).append( " )" );
    }
    //System.out.println(rsmetadata.getColumnTypeName(i));
    //System.out.println(rsmetadata.getColumnDisplaySize(i));
}
```

I am trying to create a table in MySQL using `ResultSet` metadata. But while I am executing the statement I am getting an error:

> Exception isjava.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Too big precision 19 specified for 'date_time'. Maximum is 6.

Comment: we dont know what you tried.So its hard to give the solution

Comment: Please provide us sample code. Also refer: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i am not able to paste my code

Comment: i am trying to create a table from another table in mysql database using resultset metadata

Comment: @HimanshuTiwari Define not "I am able to paste my code". Are you having trouble in entering the details in the question or is your code is not something that you can copy?

Comment: now i have provide my sample code plz help me now

Comment: What is the max column count in that for loop you will encounter? `columnCount ` ? print it in your code and debug and see.

Comment: the datetime column is showing something like date_time DATETIME( 19 ). this the issue which causing error

Comment: Then: `A DATETIME or TIMESTAMP value can include a trailing fractional seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision. In particular, as of MySQL 5.6.4` [Refer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html)

Comment: but my database of old table and new table is same. then why datetime is showing (19)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are specifying a precision value on a `timestamp` field. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11703117/284538), you really can't do that. I would suggest putting a conditional statement in there to make it check for whether the field is a timestamp field and avoid using the precision setting if it is.